Gazebo performance decrease after some time or certain number of service call
I'm running an evolutionary algorithm using ROS 2 Humble and Gazebo Fortress. For this, I need to call Gazebo services to stop/start the simulation and to move various objects in the environment, including my robot. What I noticed is after calling these commands, the performance of the simulations slows down, especially because a lot of times the service call fails.
What I did to test the performance is implementing a simple simulation scenario, without any evolutionary algorithm on top of it. This simulation consists of just stopping the simulation, moving the robot and the objects, and restarting the simulation for 10 seconds.
I plotted the data related to this behavior in the following plots. These show for each hour of simulation the total number of service calls, the service calls that didn't give back a successful answer, and the percentage of service calls that gave a successful answer. Please ignore the hour 25.



Does anyone know how this is possible or has noticed the same problem? Any help will be appreciated.
